# Storing numbers from input and making sum

Tags: javascript

I'm making a page that you can add a product name and price, and when you click the button "Enregistrer" it prints the product you asked for in a `<ul>` (this is working) and I want to make the total price and average price, here what I'm trying to do is pushing each number written in the input to the list `prixtotal` and then make a sum using a `for` loop.
Nothing works here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Produit et Prix</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    .container{
        border:1px solid black;
        width:20%;
    }   

    .buttoncont{
        padding-left:5%;
    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function afficher(){
        const prixtotal = [0];  
        var prodcount = 0;
        var prixmoyen = 0;
        var x = document.getElementById("produit").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("prix").value;
        if(x=="" || y=="" || (y.toLowerCase() != y.toUpperCase()) ){
            alert("Please re-check your information");
        }
        else{
        // prodcount++;
        prixtotal.push(Number(y));
        for (int i=0; i<prixtotal.length(); i++){
            var sum += prixtotal[i];
        }
        // alert(prixtotal);
        // prixmoyen += (prixtotal/prodcount);
        document.getElementById("ulist").innerHTML += "<li>" + document.getElementById("produit").value + "</li>";
        document.getElementById("pt").innerHTML += sum;
        // document.getElementById("pm").innerHTML += prixmoyen;
            }
        }   
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container"> <br>
    <span style="padding-left:10%"> Produit : </span> <input type="text" name="produit" id="produit"> <br> <br>
    <span style="padding-left:10%"> Prix : &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span> <input type="text" name="prix" id="prix"> <br> <br>
</div>
<br>
<div class="buttoncont"> 
    <button onclick="afficher()"> Enregistrer a la liste </button>
</div>

<div class="listcont"> <br> <br>
    <b> &nbsp;&nbsp; Your List : </b>
    <ul type="square" id="ulist">
    </ul> <br> <br>
    <span id="pt"> Prix Total : </span> <br> <br>
    <span id="pm"> Prix Moyen : </span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I did at first is before making a `list`, is making `prixtotal = 0` and then adding the number from the input to it after parsing it, but it concatenate the number and nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, there is a lot of code that you can simplify, check below:

```js
// These values can be outside the function so they can be used globally
var prixtotal = 0;
var prodcount = 0;
var prixmoyen = 0;

function afficher() {

  var x = document.getElementById("produit").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("prix").value;
  
  if (x == "") {
    alert("Please re-check your information");
  } else {
    prodcount++; // Increase number of products
    prixtotal+= Number(y);  // Calculate total price
    document.getElementById("ulist").innerHTML += "<li>" + document.getElementById("produit").value + "</li>";
    document.getElementById("pt").innerHTML = "Prix Total : " + prixtotal;
    // Divide total by number of products and keep 2 decimal places
    document.getElementById("pm").innerHTML = "Prix Moyen : " + (prixtotal/prodcount).toFixed(2);
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.buttoncont {
  padding-left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> <br>
  <span style="padding-left:10%"> Produit : </span> <input type="text" name="produit" id="produit"> <br> <br>
  <span style="padding-left:10%"> Prix : &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span> <input type="number" name="prix" id="prix"> <br> <br>
</div>
<br>
<div class="buttoncont">
  <button onclick="afficher()"> Enregistrer a la liste </button>
</div>

<div class="listcont"> <br> <br>
  <b> &nbsp;&nbsp; Your List : </b>
  <ul type="square" id="ulist">
  </ul> <br> <br>
  <span id="pt"> Prix Total : </span> <br> <br>
  <span id="pm"> Prix Moyen : </span>
</div>
```

Comment: but here i cant add numbers, i entered 50 then 100 the result was of prix total 050100

Comment: Thanks man it worked! I was trying at first ```prixtotal += Number(y)``` but I think it never worked because of these variables inside the function so everytime i call it it became 0.
Then the average price worked when I put ```.toFixed(2)```
Thanks

Comment: Yes that might be it. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Refactor of code needed.

1. `prixtotal`: create outside of the function, so easy to maintain
2. `x = Number(x)`: convert number once you get it.
3. `<li>`: You can iterate whole element and create list once, than add in html
4. For HTML, Always create a separate element, and update it. Dont to `innnerHTML +` ex: `<span> Prix Total : <span id="pt"></span></span>` It is ugly, later u can refactor.

```js
let prixtotal = []

function afficher() {
    const prodcount = 0;
    const prixmoyen = 0;
    let x = document.getElementById("produit").value;
    let y = document.getElementById("prix").value;
    x = Number(x)
    y = Number(y)
    if (x && y) {
        let sum = 0;
        prixtotal.push({
            x,
            y
        });
        let list = ""
        for (let i = 0; i < prixtotal.length; i++) {
            sum += prixtotal[i].y;
            list += `<li><p>${prixtotal[i].x}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>${prixtotal[i].y}</span></p></li>`;
        }
        document.getElementById("ulist").innerHTML = list
        document.getElementById("pt").innerText = sum;
    } else {
        alert("Please re-check your information");

    }

}
```

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 20%;
}

.buttoncont {
    padding-left: 5%;
}

#ulist {
    border: 1px solid #f9f;
    width: 200px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#ulist li,  #ulist li p {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f9f;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> <br>
    <span style="padding-left:10%"> Produit : </span> <input type="text" name="produit" id="produit"> <br> <br>
    <span style="padding-left:10%"> Prix : &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span> <input type="text" name="prix"
        id="prix"> <br> <br>
</div>
<br>
<div class="buttoncont">
    <button onclick="afficher()"> Enregistrer a la liste </button>
</div>

<div class="listcont"> <br> <br>
    <b> &nbsp;&nbsp; Your List : </b>
    <ul type="square" id="ulist">
    </ul> <br> <br>
    <p>Prix Total : <span id="pt"></span></p>
    <p>Prix Moyen : <span id="pm"></span></p>
</div>
```